# SQL Insert Timestamp Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values from two columns (`user_id`, `team_id`) in my `user` table to a junction table of `company_team`. However, I have gotten errors with two different attempts to insert values for my `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in `company_team` and don't know how to work past them.

**In the first attempt I simply wanted to update the two field with the value from the equivalent fields in the `user` table: (Note columns on both tables are DATETIME)**

```
INSERT INTO `company_team` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`user_id`, `company_id`)
SELECT `user_id`, `company_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
FROM `user` AS `u`
WHERE `u`.`company_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

Error:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

**Then I tried just using the current date/time at record creation:**

```
INSERT INTO `company_team` (NOW(),NOW(),`user_id`, `company_id`)
SELECT `user_id`, `company_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
FROM `user` AS `u`
WHERE `u`.`company_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOW(),NOW(),`user_id`, `organization_id`)
SELECT `user_id`, `company_id`, `' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing an insert, the *names* of the values don't matter.  They are matches by position.

So, I think you just need to re-order the columns:

```
INSERT INTO company_team (user_id, company_id, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT user_id, company_id, created_at, updated_at
    FROM `user` u
    WHERE u.company_id IS NOT NULL;
```

This changes the order on the `INSERT` side.  Perhaps as a matter of habit I put the created and updated dates at the end -- or set them automatically by giving them default values.

Comment: Thank you! Minor lapse in remembering that the ordering of the columns is strict.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the items in the same order as the columns listed in the INSERT part:

```
INSERT INTO `company_team` (`user_id`, `company_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT `user_id`, `company_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
FROM `user` AS `u`
WHERE `u`.`company_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second try you used `NOW()` as columns to insert into. The values (and the `NOW()` functions) should be on the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In your second effort you used NOW() for created_at and updated_at values. This would not insert values from table `user` but your current timestamp. In this case it would be easier to simply define 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for value `created_at` and 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for value `updated_at` correspondingly when you create table `company_team`

Consequently you don't need to activelly set them at creation time, as they will be populated automatically